# swift screen move when keyboard appears

Tags: swift, keyboard

I have a textview and a text field on my screen and I want move screen when edit textview. 
This is my code

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

 //   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

    print("addd observer")

}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
 //   NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ sender: Notification) {
    let keyboardSize = (sender.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
    print("keyboardwillshow")
    ksize = keyboardSize?.height

}


@objc func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("textviewedit")
        boxview.frame.origin.y -= ksize
        print("textview")



}
@objc func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    print("textvieweditend")
    boxview.frame.origin.y = 0

}
```

It works when I just edit textview. However, if I edit the textview right after focus on the textfield(without exit keyboard) it doens't work.
I already checked that `textviewDidBeginEditing()` is called but the screen doesn't move.. How can I solve this? All advises are welcome!

Comment: Instead of using `boxview.frame.origin.y` to change frame, I suggest to use `boxview.center`. Maybe it will work.

Comment: @trungduc thanks for your advice. I tried but it seems in same situation. It works when I just edit textview but, when I edit textview, after editing text field, it doesn't work....

Comment: Please refer to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31124676/3882414

Comment: Please refer to these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31124676/3882414 https://stackoverflow.com/a/46140997/3882414

Comment: @rami Thanks rami!!!!! I add self.view.Layoutifneeded() to my keyboardwillappear() and it works! I catch clue by your advice!! Repeat, Thanks u very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I add `self.view.Layoutifneeded()` to keyboardwillchange() and it works!! thanks everybody.